# Regex : string must contain a-z and A-Z and 0-9

Tags: mysql, regex, stored-procedures

I'm using a stored procedure to validate the input parameter. The input parameter must contain a-z and A-Z and 0-9.
for Example:
`aS78fhE0` -> Correct
`76AfbRZt` -> Correct
`76afbrzt` -> Incorrect(doesn't contain Upper Case A-Z)
`asAfbRZt` -> Incorrect(doesn't contain Numeric 0-9)
`4QA53RZJ` -> Incorrect(doesn't contain Lower Case a-z)

what Regular Expression that can validate the input parameter like above example,.?
Many Thanks,
Praditha

**UPDATE**
Others character except Alphanumeric are not allowed
I'm Using MySQL version 5

Comment: Are any *other* characters allowed?

Comment: no, just like the above sample..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further from Johns Post and subsequent comments:

The MySql you require would be

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP BINARY '[a-z]'
                        AND mycolumn REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]'
                        AND mycolumn REGEXP BINARY '[0-9]'
```

Add additional

```
AND mycolum REGEXP BINARY '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'
```

If you *only* want Alphanumerics in the string

Comment: I don't understand, I just tried like this `SELECT *
FROM
  tb_m_menu
WHERE
  'aa11' REGEXP '[A-Z]';` , but it return TRUE. I think there is no different between upper and lower case in MySQL.

Comment: You need to use binary strings to make the regex case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

With look-ahead assertion you could do like this:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$/
```

***update***: It seems mysql doesn't support look around assertions.

Comment: Are stored procedures using a different regex engine? Because MySQL's engine does not support lookaround assertions.

Comment: This matches arbitrary characters, for example '%aAA9' passes this regex

Comment: his question is ambiguous... it doesn't say that other characters are not allowed.

Comment: only Alphanumeric are allowed on this validation. @JohnCorbett: I've try your regex, but it's return error `Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`

Comment: I just looked at the docs. It seems that your solution won't work because the regex engine doesn't support lookaround.

Answer (score 2):

You could split it up into 3 separate regex to test for each case.

`[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, and `[0-9]`

and the results of those matches together, and you can achieve the result you're looking for.

EDIT:

if you're only looking to match alphanumerics, you should do `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` as suggested by Ed Head in the comments

Comment: If it is required for the string to just contain only those characters, add an extra regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: That doesn't work because it doesn't allow for characters that are not alphabetical or numerical

Comment: Please re-read - I wrote **JUST** - and that was before the update.

Comment: got it, 6:30 am will do that haha

Comment: I've tried this, with this input parameter `76afbrzt` it should be incorrect, but it return correct. I've tried this query `select * from tb_m_menu where '76afbrzt' regexp '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$';`

Comment: @Praditha - As John is probably now either eating breakfast or off to work, see my POST for a solution that will work.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is leads to a long expression becuase i will permutate over all 6 possibilities the found capital letter, small letter and the needed number can be arranged in the string:

```
^(.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[0-9].*|
  .*[a-z].*[0-9].*[A-Z].*|
  .*[A-Z].*[a-z].*[0-9].*|
  .*[A-Z].*[0-9].*[a-z].*|
  .*[0-9].*[a-z].*[A-Z].*|
  .*[0-9].*[A-Z].*[a-z].*)$
```

Edit: Forgot the `.*` at the end and at the beginning.

Comment: This allows strings like `#a*B$1` which (as the OP has now pointed out) should be illegal.

Comment: I've tried like this, but it still incorrect `SELECT *
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  'aS78fhE0'
  REGEXP '^(.*[a-z].*[A-Z].*[0-9].*|
  .*[a-z].*[0-9].*[A-Z].*|
  .*[A-Z].*[a-z].*[0-9].*|
  .*[A-Z].*[0-9].*[a-z].*|
  .*[0-9].*[a-z].*[A-Z].*|
  .*[0-9].*[A-Z].*[a-z].*)$
'`

Comment: Try removeing the whitespaces from that regular expression!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support lookaround assertions, therefore you'll have to spell it out for the regex engine (assuming that *only* those characters are legal):

```
^(
[A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|
[A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*|
[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|
[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*|
[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*|
[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
)$
```

or, in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP BINARY "^([A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*[a-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)$";
```

Answer (score -1):

[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*

Comment: This either allows invalid strings like `"%§&aA0§$%"` or (if you add anchors around it) rejects valid strings like `"aA0aA0"`.